# Copying/ Assigning char * pointer data

Tags: c, pointers

Very new to C, I have an object

```
struct Object {
     char *request;  
};
```

And I have pointers in a function

```
 char *req = NULL; 
 char *request = NULL;
```

I eventually need to copy req to request so that request has the data, but will not be influenced by later changes to req.

I believe I need something in the order of

```
if(!request){
    request = malloc(sizeof(req));
    memcpy(request, req, sizeof(*req));
}
```

Later in the function I assign request to Object's request

```
Object->request = request;
```

Currently when I try and print the object's request I get

```
THE REQUESTED FILE IS CALLED f▒F▒
```

Very new to C and am not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof(req)` gives you the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg do i need sizeof(*req) for both instances ?

Comment: @guy_sensei No. Both `sizeof`s are wrong. See my answer.

Comment: going to try some helpful answers soon (thanks you !) , but I'm not giving any downvotes to any users (must be someone else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not allocate enough space. Assuming that req points to a C string, you need to call strlen to see how much space you need:

```
if(!request){
    request = malloc(strlen(req)+1);
    strcpy(request, req);
}
```

Note the addition of one to the length, it's there to accommodate null terminator.

Comment: AFAIK there was a function "strdup" that does the job of strlen, malloc, and strcpy.

Comment: @harper I agree. The only problem with `strdup` is that it is a Posix function, which is not part of C standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You don't allocate enough space for the entire string.

When you use `sizeof` on a pointer, you only get the size of the pointer, not the size of the array it points to.

So this:

```
request = malloc(sizeof(req));
```

Only allocates enough space for 8 or 4 bytes depending on your system. You need to keep track of the size of the array elsewhere, or use `strlen()`, which loops through the string until it finds a `NUL` character (`\0`), which all strings in C end with.

Similarly, `sizeof(*req)` returns the size of a `char`, which is always 1 byte. Again, you aren't accounting for the length of the entire string.

A best fix would be to do something like this:

```
size_t len = strlen(req) + 1; /* leave space for '\0' character */
request = malloc(len); /* allocate memory */
memcpy(request, req, len); /* copy the string */
```

Or if you don't mind getting the length of the string twice:

```
request = malloc(strlen(req) + 1); /* leave space for '\0' character */
strcpy(request, req); /* use strcpy() instead of memcpy(), which gets the length itself */
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If something is wrong with this answer, please allow me to correct it.

Comment: yeah, maybe sometimes people downvote "just like that"- you never know:)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Seems odd if they're doing it out of spite or something like that because they incur a penalty also. Oh well, I guess.

Comment: never mind, normally it would be better to see feedback, but that is how it works, anyway, these answers will hang out here, and throughout time, community will check if smth is wrong with them or not.